# How to override Plone's display menu for special case content?

Tags: plone

To get a one-off view on a Plone folder I do something like this (not all code shown):

In `configure.zcml`:

```
<!-- Marker interface. Set this on the folder through the ZMI
     interfaces tab.
  -->
<interface interface=".interfaces.IMySpecialFolder" />
```

In `browser/configure.zcml`:

```
<!-- Special case view. Set as the folder's view through the ZMI
     properties tab (layout property).
  -->
<browser:page
  for="..interfaces.IMySpecialFolder"
  name="special"
  template="special.pt"
  permission="zope2.View"
  />
```

This works great, but I would like to control the folder's display menu to list **only** my special case view. I can add it, and it shows up only on my marked folder, but I have to change the site-wide ATFolder FTI.

In `browser/configure.zcml`:

```
<include package="plone.app.contentmenu" />

<browser:menuItem
  for="..interfaces.IMySpecialFolder"
  menu="plone_displayviews"
  title="Special view"
  action="@@special"
  description="Special case folder view"
  />
```

In `profiles/default/types/Folder.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="Folder">
 <property name="view_methods" purge="False">
  <element value="special"/>
 </property>
</object>
```

Of course I cannot remove the existing available view methods without affecting every folder on the site.

Is there a way to do this one-off display menu tweaking without changing a content type's FTI?

Actually, it seems like this problem has been tackled before. [p4a.z2utils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/p4a.z2utils) patches `CMFDynamicViewFTI` to get the list of available views from an `IDynamicallyViewable` adapter lookup. ([dateable.chronos](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateable.chronos) uses this mechanism for its folder calendar views). So my question becomes:

Is there a way to do this one-off display menu tweaking without changing a content type's FTI and without patching Plone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I've realised that the most straightforward way to achieve one-off folder views is to follow the pattern Plone itself applies in the `Members` folder: a PythonScript `index_html` that calls the custom view, e.g.

```
member_search=context.restrictedTraverse('member_search_form')
return member_search()
```

`Products.CMFPlone` illustrates [how to setup such a PythonScript with a GenericSetup import handler](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/4.1.0/Products/CMFPlone/setuphandlers.py#L348-354).

In retrospect I realise I didn't need the marker interface in my question scenario. It's not necessary here in the answer either.

Note that this solution doesn't result in "the folder's display menu listing only my special case view" as I asked, but does away with the display menu altogether. I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 3):

The plone display menu builder uses `ISelectableBrowserDefault` to get available options in the Display menu (see 
http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.app.contentmenu/trunk/plone/app/contentmenu/menu.py#L220)

So I think (but I haven't tried this) that if you define an adapter for a more specific interface (in your case `IMySpecialFolder`) that provides the `Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.interface.ISelectableBrowserDefault` it should work.

The adapter should have the methods required by `plone.app.contentmenu.menu.DisplayMenu` above.

Comment: `ISelectableBrowserDefault` is but one source; display menu code *also* looks at the context itself and those methods still consult the FTI.

Comment: Read up on the [interface definition](https://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/CMFDynamicViewFTI/trunk/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/interfaces.py#L84) and the [concrete implementation](https://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/CMFDynamicViewFTI/trunk/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py#L30). The latter is a mix-in used as a base class for Archetypes, so you cannot easily use it for an adapter, but you can delegate calls to it from your adapter.

Comment: @martijn-pieters: I read the implementation, but the link in my answer is to the contentmenu implementation, which uses the adapter. So I think it should work.

Comment: @marcosfromero I was confirming it'll work beautifully, and I wanted to give the OP additional resources. The links to interface definition of `ISelectableBrowserDefault` and it's concrete implementation were to augment your answer, not to criticise it! :-)

Comment: Thanks @marcosfromero and @MartijnPieters, but I cannot get a ISelectableBrowserDefault adapter to 'take'. Even tried with `for="*"` expecting the ZCA to report a clash, but nothing. Are you able to try for yourself?

Comment: @dan-jacka: you should use ``ISelectableBrowserDefault`` as ``provides`` attribute and ``IMySpecialFolder`` as ``for`` attribute. And then, your custom ``factory`` implementation.

Comment: @marcosfromero yes, that is what I'm trying. When that didn't work I tried with the more general `for` attribute.

Comment: Thanks again Marcos and Martijn. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the `ISelectableBrowserDefault` adapter doesn't work because [the BrowserDefaultMixin class implements that interface directly](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/CMFDynamicViewFTI/tags/4.0.2/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py#L39) and so that "null adapter" will always be returned by the ZCA adapter lookup machinery regardless of any more specific adapter.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could have solved it is using traversalhook to register menu items, or in this case, unregister menu items, or register menu items with conditions that make them not appear. With the traversal hook you can use a marker interface to make it just happen in a certain folder, subsection or page.
You can see where we implemented similar code here

https://github.com/collective/collective.listingviews/blob/master/src/collective/listingviews/browser/views/controlpanel.py#L105

In this case we just wanted to register new display menu items dynamically based on control panel configuration.